# How to subtract a data from multiple columns by considering previous reminder in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

I have this set of data where I want to sum BT(which is 0.8) data on Year,Month,EID basis and then subtract it in IN & make IN 0, then remaining(0.5) subtract from MT & make MT 0 then remaining(0.4) subtract from NLT & make NLT 0 then remaining if left (0.2) from VT & make VT 0

Please note, the subtraction happens in sequence IN>MT>NLT>VT

This is getting complex as I go on solving, if any one help me out with solution or clue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your final result also. Do you need only 1 row at last or all rows having all 0s.

Comment: In the end I need all columns having all 0s. unless BT has a remainder I need to subtract value in sequence to IN>MT>NLT>VT

Comment: If BT has an amount lesser than all the columns, How will you consider which row should remain the value as there is no column to order the table.

Comment: This logic applies when there is BT value (any value > 0), then we should subtract from other columns. if BT = 0.2 then it should subtract only from IN rest will be as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear if you want to change the existing rows or aggregate and have a single row output. If it is the latter then you can use:

```sql
SELECT year,
       month,
       eid,
       GREATEST(SUM(bt-"IN"-mt-nlt-vt),0) AS bt,
       GREATEST(SUM("IN"-bt),0) AS "IN",
       GREATEST(LEAST(SUM("IN"+mt-bt),SUM(mt)),0) AS mt,
       GREATEST(LEAST(SUM("IN"+mt+nlt-bt),SUM(nlt)),0) AS nlt,
       GREATEST(LEAST(SUM("IN"+mt+nlt+vt-bt),SUM(vt)),0) AS vt
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY year, month, eid
```

Which, for the sample data (aggregating all your sample data into a single row and then expanding with various different months to test different conditions):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (year, month, eid, bt, "IN", mt, nlt, vt) AS
SELECT 2022, 1, 123456, 0.8, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2022, 2, 123456, 0.8, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2022, 3, 123456, 0.8, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2022, 4, 123456, 0.8, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | YEAR | MONTH | EID | BT | IN | MT | NLT | VT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022 | 1 | 123456 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
> | 2022 | 2 | 123456 | .1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
> | 2022 | 3 | 123456 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | .1 |
> | 2022 | 4 | 123456 | 0 | 0 | 0 | .1 | .3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5233c9f8f9781a05b412062a5377fce0)*

Comment: Rather than row-wise subtraction, As per my understanding, this is column-wise subtraction. So, .1 in ro2 should be subtracted from NLT also. As you can see from the example, No column has data in the first 4 rows still values from BT get subtracted from column order.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I am not doing row-wise subtraction. There are 4 different months in my sample data which represent different cases in the data and I have pre-aggregated all the OP's rows  into my first row of data for simplicity.

Comment: Thank you so much @MT0 it is working as expected